# In Python, how do I make my program automatically exit after 5 minutes?

Tags: python, time-limiting

I am making a text adventure code for my computer science class. The player is in a school setting, trying to figure out who the murderer is. I have not finished the code yet, but there will be only one correct ending where the player finds the murderer and the game can be replayed as many times as the player wants. I want to set a time limit on my game, so the player only has 5 minutes to find the correct way to the murderer. How do I do that? Is there a module that I should download? This is my code:

```
school_map = """This is the map of your school.
-------------------------------------------
| classroom A | classroom B | classroom C |
|______ ______|_______ _____|______ ______|
|                                         |
|-------   ---------|                     |
|                   |---------   ---------|
|     cafeteria     |                     |
|                   |                     |
|___________________|         gym         |
|                   |                     |
|   locker rooms                          |
|___________________|_____________________|
|              ☘️                    |
|                 garden             |
|                                  |
-------------------------------------------
"""

answer_yes = ["yes", "Yes", "y", "Y", "YES"]
answer_no = ["no", "No", "n", "N", "NO"]

def get_choice(prompt) -> int:
    while True:
        choice = input(prompt).lower()
        if choice == "x":
            print(school_map)
        elif choice in "12":
            return int(choice)
        else:
            print("Value must be 1 or 2.")


while True:
    print("WELCOME TO LIVRE DE LA MORT.")
    print("*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.")
    print(" ")
    name = input("What is your name? ")
    print(f"You are a genius high school senior, {name}, whose goal in life is to bring justice to the world.")
    print(school_map)
    print("If you want to see the map again, input 'X' at any given time.")
    print("You are skipping gym class in the locker rooms and looking out a window when you see a notebook fall from the sky.")
    if get_choice(
        "You can either: 1 - go and pick it up, or 2 - ignore it: "
    ) == 1:
        print("You pick up the notebook and find instructions written on the inside.")
        print("WELCOME.")
        print("I AM THE LIVRE DE LA MORT.")
        print("SINCE YOU HAVE PICKED ME UP, YOU ARE THE CHOSEN ONE.")
        print("THERE IS A MURDERER AMONGST THIS SCHOOL. HE WRITES THE NAME OF ANY PERSON IN THIS NOTEBOOK, AND THEY DIE WITHIN THE NEXT 5 MINUTES.")
        print("I WANT TO END THIS INJUSTICE AGAINST THE WORLD - AS THE CRIMINAL IS GAINING TOO MUCH POWER.")
        if get_choice(
            "WILL YOU: 1 - JOIN ME IN THIS BATTLE FOR JUSTICE AND HUNT DOWN THE MURDERER, or 2 - PUT ME BACK DOWN AND HAVE YOUR MEMORY WIPED? "
        ) == 1:
            print("Good. We shall work together.")
            print("There was a body found in either classroom A or Classroom B.")
            if get_choice(
                "You can either: 1 - check out classroom A, or 2 - check out Classroom B: "
            ) == 1:
                print("You have entered classroom A.")
                print("You have not found a body.")
                if get_choice(
                    "Do you want to: 1 - check out classroom B, or 2 - go to gym class: "
                ) == 1:
                    print("You have entered Classroom B.")
                    print("You found a body of 16-year-old girl, Jessa Silverman!")
                    break
                else:
                    print("You have entered the gym.")
                    print("In the corner, you see a group of people huddled around in a circle.")
                    break
            else:
                print("You have entered Classroom B.")
                print("You found a body of 16-year-old girl, Jessa Silverman!")
                break
        else:
            print("Your memory has been wiped.")
    else:
        print("You graduate high school and work a 8-6 job for the rest of your life as a police officer. ")
        
    playagain = input("Would you like to play again? ")
    while playagain:
        if playagain in answer_yes:
            print("ok.")
            print(" ")
            print("*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.")
        elif playagain in answer_no:
            print("You are the weak link. Goodbye.")
            exit()
        else:
            playagain = input("Would you like to play again? ")
```

Comment: on start store the datetime.datetime.now ... in between check how much time passed (maybe on each action taken by the player) ... if more then 5 minutes are gone by, exit().

Answer (score 0):

Use the `alarm` signal to trigger a handler that exits your program.

```
import sys
import signal


def alarm_handler(signum, frame):
    sys.exit("Times up!")


signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, alarm_handler)
signal.alarm(5*60)

# Proceed with your game here...
```

Comment: What do you mean by "actually"?